# Combine isset() with a mysql query to create dynamic queries

Tags: php

I have done some looking but to be honest I just dont know what exactly to search. What I am trying to do is create a dynamic query as the tittle says. That is, one where I query only the variables that are sent to the php file. For example if I want to look up users but I only know their last name and username however for another user I know his firstname and email. I want to give the search form many fields and create a query based on what fields were entered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating SQL query based on URL parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921077/generating-sql-query-based-on-url-parameters) and [...](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20mysql%20query%20conditions%20on%20url%20parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build up a list of WHERE clauses first and then add these into your query. For example:

```
$where = "";

if (isset($firstname) {
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);
    $where .= "AND firstname='$firstname'";
}

if (isset($lastname) {
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
    $where .= "AND lastname='$lastname'";
}

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 ".$whereClause);
```

Of course you will need to change the table/row/etc names and add extra `if (isset` sections for each attribute.